# Ajax POST 302 : Variable more than 1MB giving 302 redirect by Controller

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Need to send **updated html** from front end side to my spring mvc controller . if i have the **file size more than 1MB** the contrller throwing me back **302 redirect for ajax call** .

Below code contains following issue :

```
var allHtmlContent = document.getElementById('#iframeId').contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
    $.ajax({
        url : context + "/someControllerMethod",
        cache : false,
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            htmlText : encodeURIComponent(allHtmlContent)
        },
        dataType : "text",
        success : function(b) {

        },
        error: function() {
           }
    });
```

here **allHtmlContent** variable contains all the of the HTML inside iFrame. if that iFrame loaded by file which is more than 1mb size i am getting 302 redirect by contrller so ajax is displaying that error in browser network.

is there any way to resolve this issue so that i can POST variable size more than 1mb .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: 302 is no error, only a redirect.

Answer (score 1):

In nginx.conf file set the client_max_body_size to 20MB(your choice) , it means request object can hold this much of data when we do AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is related to **maximum size of a request.**

You can try below code into your `web.config` to set the maximum size of the request.

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1000000" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

The `<requestLimits>` element specifies limits on HTTP requests that are processed by the Web server. These limits include the maximum size of a request

Comment: this web.config file , will it be available in the spring mvc application?

Comment: where i can this configuration file.

Comment: this is only for ASP.NET

Comment: this Configuration is working fine for the first request but again for the same file second request is failing and its giving back 302, any idea what would be the problem?